# How can i use full CPU resources with Gitlab server?

Tags: git, gitlab

I installed Gitlab server in an AWS EC2 instance, with 36 CPU cores.
But in monitoring tab in Gitlab admin page, Gitlab seems to recognize only 10 cores.
I cannot find this kind of parameters in Gitlab configuration file.
How can i use full CPU resource with Gitlab server?

[Gitlab monitoring page shows 10 cores in this system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQQ8M.png)